# How to bring an image to the Foreground on run time in Unity?

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a game where I have to display different pictures when different buttons are clicked.

The problem when one button is pressed image appears behind all the other buttons (Except the button which is clicked to display that image). I have attached screenshots to describe my problem better. Please suggest a solution to overcome this problem.

**Screenshot of the game with all Buttons :**

[image]

**Button when clicked Image appears but all the  other buttons are infront of the image :**

[image]

Comment: As alternative I would recommend using the [Unity UI System](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) introduced in Unity 4.6 instead of OnGUI().

Answer (score 0):

put a boolean to hide the buttons if the image is shown.

Comment: I have created buttons on run time using      if (GUI.Button (new rect(),""))  .  How can i refer to a particular button when other button is pressed ?

Comment: do something like this

bool showImage = false;

if(showImage)

else
{
   if (GUI.Button (new rect))
        showImage = true;
}

Answer (score 0):

You need guiDepth

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html

```
yourButton.guiDepth = 0;
```

0 = on top of everything

Comment: But the button is created  on run time, How can i use this ?

Comment: Well, don't you have a reference to that button ?

Comment: I created it in the Void OnGUI() function.

Comment: I see, my advice is the same that JeanLuc, use the (not so) new UI system. You might have a bit of work to adapt your current project, but it will be so much easier to manage then.